# Is possible refresh page and open modal after button refresh? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click in my `btn-success` to refresh my page and open a modal after 1 second when page was refreshed.

So i tried this,but its not working, it only refreshes the page.
*I need to refresh my page to update my sessions.*
Is it possible to do that?
If it is,how i will do that?

```
jQuery(".btn-success").click(function(){
  location.reload();
  setInterval( function(){ 
    jQuery(".modal_pop").trigger('click');
   return false;
  }  , 1000 );
```

Comment: You'd have to persist some piece of data *outside* of the context of the page.  In a cookie, local storage, server-side, etc.  Some element of information that the page checks for when it loads.  When the page loads, check for that data and use it to determine whether or not to show the modal.  When the button is clicked, update that data before reloading the page.

Comment: Is the modal needed only when you refresh the page on a button click? or do you need that on every load?

Comment: when the user click on confirm order,the page will refresh and open a modal asking if the client ready to finalize his order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Call ur document as .php  e.g. sample.php

```
<php 

$modal = $_GET['modal'];

if ($modal == 1) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
setTimeout(function() {
$(\".modal_pop\").css("display", "block");
}, 1000);
</script>";
}

?>



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(".btn-success").click(function(){
  window.location.href = 'sample.php?modal=1';
</script>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: it only refresh my page,modal is not popping

Comment: i fix it, u just used `jQuery('.modal_pop').trigger('click');` in the script you wrote

Comment: Basically what my code does it refreshes the page but this time it inserts GET PHP variable in URL... Than I have PHP script which receives that variable before page shows up to user (as PHP server side) and if that variable is received on next page load it inserts time out function that will start after 1s... You can anything you like to that timeout function... Code that I posted worked for me...

Comment: Ur welcome ;) By tha way same thing is possible without PHP.. I dont have ready code for this but idea would be to use urdomain.com#sometext in URL and after refresh jQuery gets that text and does something..